# Bootstrap 2.3.2 navbar selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm using the latest bootsrap to display a navbar with the following items.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <ul id="navigation" class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav_btns nav-selected"><a href="~/home/index">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav_btns"><a href="~/manage/users">User</a></li>
            <li class="nav_btns"><a href="#">Document</a></li>
            <li class="nav_btns dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Account <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul id="my-account-dropdown" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#edit-accountsetting" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> Settings</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="~/account/changepassword" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Change password</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> Language</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="~/account/logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Log out</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

The problem is highlighting the item that is selected or clicked. All I know is that I need to add a class to the item "nav-selected" to highlight the selected item. How can I accomplish that every time I click an item the nav-selected class will be implemented. This navbar is on a masterpage. But it seems that It is always reloading eveytime I switch pages and the "navbar-selected" is going back to the default item. I tried using javascript on this.

```
$(".nav_btns").click(function ()
{
    $(".nav_btns").removeClass();
    $(this).addClass("nav_btns navbar-selected")
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Bootstrap 2.3.2 is **not** the latest Boostrap version and what you want to do is best handled server-side

Comment: Can you give my a sample?

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP, I would assign a variable on each page right at the top; the value of that variable determined by the current page. I would then include a menu, and use if statements to determine if the current menu item/list item is active.

Variable:

Included php:

```
<ul class="nav sf-menu">
   <li class="menuItem <?php if($menulocation == "MenuItem1"){echo("nav_btns navbar-selected");}; ?>"><a href="index.php">MenuItem1</a></li>
   <li class="menuItem  <?php if($menulocation == "MenuItem2"){echo("nav_btns navbar-selected");}; ?>"><a href="login.php">MenuItem2</a></li>
    <li class="menuItem  <?php if($menulocation == "MenuItem3"){echo("nav_btns navbar-selected");}; ?>"><a href="help.php">MenuItem3</a>
 </ul>
```

Comment: I'm using MVC C# by the way.

Comment: I am sure you can the same concept in any language.